I'm Simply trying to print to a network printer using a C# program in .net 8. I keep getting though "Settings to access printer are not valid"
static void Main()
{

    string pdfFilePath = @"C:\AREA PDFS\new-ocr.pdf";


    string printerName = @"\\";
    PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
    {
        PrinterName = printerName,
        PrintToFile = true,
        PrintFileName = pdfFilePath
    };


    PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
    printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
    printDocument.Print();

    Console.WriteLine("File sent to printer successfully.");
}

I took out the printer name and the Full file path just for this question. Just letting you all know so that's not looked at as the issue.
I am unable to get past the "PrintDocument.Print(); part. I always end up with the error "Settings to access printer are not valid" Is there a better way to code this? My thoughts as well is a printer should have default settings.
Is it required to input printer settings? I am trying to print just for the fact of "proof of concept". I can then make it look nice in an actual windows application but I am getting stuck on actually printing the pdf.
